# Updating the LAF of a different class

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, swingutilities

In a "Battleship" program I wrote, I included the possibility to change the "look and feel" of a program to SystemDefault, "Metal" (Java Default) or "Motif" (also included in Java). If you choose the desired LAF from a `JComboBox` (--> changes a predefined String, `lookFeel`) and press a confirm button, `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookFeel)` is called, and also `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this)` and the method `updateUI()` with the following code:

```
public static void updateUI() {
        //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI();
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(colorChooser);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(shipChooser);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(guide);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(menu_bar);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(menu_general);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(menu_customization);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(lafChooser);

        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(LAN.lanframe);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(LAN.hostframe);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(LAN.joinframe);
    }
```

However, this code will not update other windows that are part of a different class. Hence, if I launch my main program, and then change the look&feel, these windows won't be affected. Those classes that actually create a frame are not a problem, but my main program just extends JFrame (something I probably wouldn't do again, but I was entirely new to Java when I started writing this program).
Now my question is: how can I change the LAF of this class?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is problem about the changing of the LAF of your main frame which is class extended from JFrame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java look and feel at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953935/java-look-and-feel-at-runtime)

Comment: by default JFrame (or another top ancessor) is target for, e.g. `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myLocalVariableForJFrame);`

Comment: considering that i tried and failed too often for my taste getting this right, I've just decided to change my main class - it now creates an instance of JFrame, instead of extending JFrame. i guess extending JFrame instead of creating an instance is probably dumb anyways ^^

Answer (score 3):

If the result of [`getSupportsWindowDecorations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html#getSupportsWindowDecorations--) is `true` for a given [`LookAndFeel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html), you can invoke [`setWindowDecorationStyle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setWindowDecorationStyle-int-) on the [`JRootPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html). A complete example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197350/230513) in *UIManager Defaults*.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to change swing applicaiton's look and feel at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165394/how-to-change-swing-applicaitons-look-and-feel-at-runtime) on how to call updateComponentTreeUI on all windows of your application.

Note that the updateComponent**Tree**UI will recursively update all subcomponents, therefore you don't need to call it for each and every component, rather call it for all the windows (frames).

Comment: well, it didn't work if I called it only on the frame (maybe I should have called it on the root pane or whatever), but anyhow, I've already changed my program structure so that my main class no longer extends JFrame. I also wrote that in a comment below my question, but I guess you missed that. Thank you nevertheless!

Comment: Oh, one thing more: you can't update the outer LAF from native to non-native properly of a frame which is already rendered on the screen. This is a Swing limitation. You need to close the frame, change the LAF, and open it again. The updateComponentTreeUI works well for the components inside a frame, and - please check - switching between non-native LAFs, e.g. switching between variants of Metal LAF.